# How to Convert iframe to canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, iframe, html2canvas

I am trying to save all content into another page as an image.

I have explored the way to do this so I think that I need to convert that page to canvas first.

So, I have tried to use the link that I want to save that to img be an iframe in my current page first and then convert iframe to canvas but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
            }
        });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="html-content-holder" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://api.marketanyware.com/chartv2/engine/index.html?{bodyColor:%27#000000',api:{params:[{Stock:'SET',Period:'2hour',ChartList:{OHLC:true,EODHLine:true,EMA: [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 200],RSI: [7],MACDBar:false,MACD: [{ v12: 12, v26: 26, vref: 9,type:11}/*, { v1: 12, v2: 26, vref: 9}*/],Volume:true,VolumeColor:false}}]}}"></iframe>

<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
<br/>
<h3>Preview :</h3>
<div id="previewImage">
```

Answer (score 5):

#### You can't access the content of an cross-origin iframe.

Neither can html2canvas which needs to parse the DOM structure in order to be able to draw it on the canvas.

#### For same origin iframes,

html2canvas won't get by itself the content of your frame, so you'll have to pass its `contentDocument.documentElement` as parameter, otherwise it will just render an empty box.

```js
frame.onload =()=>{
  html2canvas(frame.contentDocument).then((canvas)=>{
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
  };
```

[**Link for fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt5qhnga/) since stacknippets frames are sandboxed and that we can't do anything with it...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var element = $(document.querySelector("#iframe-id")).contents().find('body')[0];
        html2canvas(element).then(canvas => {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas)
            });
```

Comment: What is '$' ? I get contents is not a function.

Comment: @smartblonde '$' refers to [jquery](https://jquery.com/). Years ago, it's was popular on the web. Modern web development uses it less and less. This particular example will not work without it being available on the page.

Answer (score 0):

as others said there is no way to access the content of an cross-origin iframe.

but if you just want to take a capture from a cross-origin iframe there is a way.

Google Chrome in it's new version has ability to capture from a specific region of page which is called **Region Capture**.
this ability is embedded in *chrome version 104 and above*.

with this ability you can capture anything in a page include iframes.

you can see the demo and example from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/region-capture/)