# Creating multiple iframes to make a curved plane with synced iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm attempting to create a curved iframe. I know it is not possible to curve an iframe, although I have been researching and found a possible solution, which is, creating multiple iframes and later on syncing them.

 I have got some of the code from this post: [Three js curved (bend) CSS3DObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241837/three-js-curved-bend-css3dobject) which served me really well, although I can't seem to curve the frames and position them correctly.

Here is the fiddle I have created:
https://jsfiddle.net/niltonsf/2cwq38tb/1/

```
var scene, camera, renderer, container;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var  createElements= function(url, divisions, parent) {
    var w = 100.0 / divisions;
    var x = 0;

    for (var x = 0; x < 100; x += w) {
      var el = document.createElement('iframe');
      el.src = url;
      var x2 = x + w;
      el.style = "clip-path:polygon(" + x + "% 0%, " + x2 + "% 0%, " + x2 + "% 100%, " + x + "% 100%);";
      var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(el);
/*       if (x > 90){
      cssObject.rotation.y = x * 0.4
      console.log(x*-1)
              cssObject.position.z = x * -1
      } else {
        cssObject.position.z = x * 1
      }
       */      
       if (x >= 95 || x <= 1) {
        /* cssObject.position.z = 0 */
       } else if (x > 60) {
        cssObject.position.z = (x * -1) * 1 + 10
       } else {
       cssObject.position.z = x * -1
       }
      parent.add(cssObject);
    }
  }
    container = new THREE.Object3D();
  createElements("https://example.com/",24,container);
    scene.add(container);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 200;
  camera.position.y = 30;
  renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {
container.rotation.y += .005;

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, the red and aqua circles are referring to the ends of the plane bend, the frames from the red circle on (until the middle of all frames) should go backwards until the green circle. On the green circle on the frames should go positive back to the aqua circle, achieving something like:
[image]

Comment: Saw your previous (deleted) question. Went searching and found this in the *three.js* examples section near the very end of the list: [three.js: 3D YouTube](https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_youtube.html). Give it time to load. Maybe you can convert it to something you can work with.

Comment: A bit of correcting on your z-axis placement to: ```if (x >= 50) { cssObject.position.z = x - 100 } else { cssObject.position.z = -x; }``` helps. But it's insufficient because the view is the usual perspective view. To correct for that, you'd also have to billboard the strips and scale them horizontally. You're likely to have better luck using a webgl view showing the shape you want and using another canvas showing the iframe as the texture on that shape.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I saw that solution, but my main issue is curving the plane as a curved monitor. I can insert videos, and html into a iframe without no issue, the problem is the curving

Comment: @Ouroborus what do you mean by applying as a texture. I have been using react three fiber and drei. Do you mean it is possible to simulate a html page, as a texture for an object? If so, how?

Comment: [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907019/how-to-convert-iframe-to-canvas) talks about it. Once you get the html drawn on a canvas, you can pull the canvas content as an image and use that as a texture. (If you wanted it to be interactive, that's unlikely to work even with your own code.)